# How to deal with legacy app storing Arabian characters in latin1 database

Tags: php, utf-8, latin1

I now work on a web-base PHP app to work with a MySQL Server database .
database is with Latin1 Character set and all Persian texts don't show properly .
database is used with a windows software Show and Save Persian texts good .
I don't want to change the charset because windows software work with that charset .

***Question:***
how can convert latin1 to utf8 to show and utf8 to latin1 for saving from my web-base PHP app , or using Persian/Arabic language on a latin1 charset database without problem ?

*note:

 one of my texts is `احمد رحمانی` when save from my windows-based software save as `ÇÍãÏ ÑÍãÇäí` and still show with `احمد رحمانی` in my old windows-based software*

*image* :  [image of database , charsets,collation and windows-based software (full Size)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGL8H.jpg)
[image: image of database , charsets,collation and windows-based software]

Comment: You cannon show arabic characters in latin 1: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537495(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Pekka not duplicate , I see others first

Comment: @JvdBerg I have a Delphi windows-based software work without problem with this database with latin1 charset , show and save Persian texts good .

Comment: @root point taken re the duplicate, I was too hasty. If you look into the database using a tool like phpMyAdmin or HeidiSQL, does the data look okay there? (Be careful not to change anything if it doesn't look okay, and always have backups)

Comment: @Pekka Thanks, i Add a note to first post , I don't want change the charset of db to utf8 because windows-based software work with latin1 and without problem with Persian/Arabic text , if I insert a text as utf8 to Database that text shown on my old windows-based software with question symbols like `???? ?? ????`.

Comment: @root I added an answer with a theory on what may be happening in your Delphi app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Edit:** Your screenshot shows that the diagnosis below is probably correct.
>
> **What to do:** Try using `iconv()` in your PHP web application. You would have to guess or find out what collation/codepage your Windows app uses.
>
> Then something like this might work:
>
> ```
> $string_decoded =  iconv("windows-1256", "utf-8", $string);
> ```
>
> You may need to experiment to get this working. Also, I *think* you need to force your database connection to use latin1 instead of UTF-8!
>
> If you ask me, this is not a good basis for your web app. You would have to convert data into a broken format all the time. You may have to break compatibility with your application, or write an import tool.

The latin1 character set does not cover Persian characters. [Proof at collation-charts.org](http://www.collation-charts.org/mysql60/mysql604.latin1_general_ci.html)

The only explanation I have why your Delphi program is able to store Arabic characters in a latin1 database is, it could be *misusing* the latin1 database to store data that isn't covered by latin1, e.g. [Windows-1256 Arabic.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc195058.aspx) So the program would store the raw bytes of each arabic character, while in fact these bytes are occupied by other, *latin* characters in the latin1 character set. But as long as was only the Delphi program storing and fetching the data, *no one noticed.*

If I'm correct in that - it's the only way I can see how what you describe could be happening - that *works* as long as only applications are involved that do this the same way, a way which is wrong really.

You should be able to confirm whether this is the case by looking at the data from a "neutral" database tool like phpMyAdmin or HeidiSQL. If you see garbage there instead of Arabic / Persian characters, I may be right.

As to *what to do* to make your PHP web app work with the same database as your Delphi app - I'm not really sure what to do to be honest. As far as I know, there is no way to force mySQL to use one encoding instead of the other. You would have to manually "re-encode" the data before fetching it into your web app. This is likely to be a painful process.

But first, try to find out what exactly is happening.

Comment: thanks I now that , this software is an old program and work with this charset and don't know who programmed this software . I try to find a way to store and show data like that . a image from database , charset,field and my windows-based program added to first post , please check it ;)

Comment: thanks but still have problem , now text show as `أ‡أچأ£أڈ أ‘أچأ£أ‡أ¤أ­` , must show as `احمد رحمانی`

Comment: @root then you will have to experiment with the code pages (instead of `Windows-1256`, that was just a guess on my part) and with the collation of the mySQL connection. I'm sorry, I have lots of work to do and can't look into this in detail....